# ReportViewer in MVC application issue

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, view, reportviewer

I have an MVC4 application that renders data to the UI without issue but when I try and display the same data in a report I see the headers for the fields from my view but I do not see any data.  The code below shows how I am providing data for said report.  The List is populated with a single row containing the expected data in a List of type ReportInfo.  I am able to see that data in the Index.cshtml page when I initially call the page in Index ActionResult but when I click the button to export into a PDF report I get a blank report, except for the headers.

My data is sourced from a View within an Oracle database and I have a reference in my application to both Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and WebForms.

Any ideas?

```
public ActionResult Report(int id)
    {
        List<ReportInfo> list = null;

        // Get Report Data
        list = GetReportInfo(id);

        Warning[] warnings;
        string mimeType;
        string[] streamids;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;

        var viewer = new ReportViewer();
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report"), "Report1.rdlc");
        viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = path;

        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", list));
        viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

        var bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

        return new FileContentResult(bytes, mimeType);
}
```

Comment: This approach works flawlessly with a DataSet generated from data in SQL Server.  I don't understand why it won't for Oracle.....ugh

Comment: Not one single response???